# using a javascript file as a background in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am aware I can use background-image: url("www.linktoimage.com/image.png"), in  css, to place an image in the background. I also know I can add a javascript file into html with  tag. My challenge is how do I apply css characteristics of a background image to my javascript file?

To add some context, the javascript file is a simple animation (randomly bouncing balls, that responds to the screen width and height. I want to place text on top of this as if it was background, but no matter what I do, text will place itself above the script, in a white box, instead of directly on top of my script. Below is the general result of my various attempts:

[image: result]

I would like to place "Welcome" on top of my javascript, as oppose to how it currently appears on top of window with a white background. My css is as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'HighTide';
  src: url('assets/HighTide.otf')

  font-family:'HighTideSans';
  src: url('assets/HighTideSans.otf')

}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  vertical-align: top;
  z-index: -1
}

.title {
  font-family:'HighTide';
  font-size: 10vw;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.enter {
  font-family:'HighTideSans';
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;  
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LockeDesign</title>
    <script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libraries/svg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class=title> WELCOME </div>
    <a href="main.html" class=enter> </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT**

Using position: absolute; works partially, all I had to do was add left: 0;
right: 0; and bottom: 50%; to re-center the text. Resizing the window would cause scrollbars to appear, which was less than desirable, so I added   overflow:hidden; to the body tag. Now this works exactly as intended, thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried position: absolute?

Comment: This worked, see my edits, thanks!

Comment: @Arkadelic  if you don't like scrollbars but still want to keep the content of the page scrollable then you could add this to your CSS

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 0px; height:0;}

Comment: @ReallyNiceCode for this specific page I do not need to scroll, however further on in development I may very well use this so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **WRAPPING**  all of the content you wish to display over the dynamic background in a single div

Example

```
<html>
  <body>

  <div id="BodyWrapper">
    <h1> This is  an HTML Page </h1>
  </div><!-- End BodyWrapper -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Then apply some Z positioning to the BodyWrapper with css

```
#BodyWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:5;}
```

> If the above is still not enough then you may have to delay the
>   showing of the body content (make sure the dynamic background
>   completely loads first).

You can set the initial display styling of the wrapper to

```
#BodyWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:1; display:none;}
```

and onLoad... call this function

```
function show_PageBody()
{  
   setTimeout(function(){ update_Wrapper(); },1000);

   function update_Wrapper()
     {
       document.getElementById('BodyWrapper').style.display='block';
       document.getElementById('BodyWrapper').style.zIndex = 5;  
     }

}
```

*You can add a css transition for the opacity of the BodyWrapper so that it fades onto the screen instead of just appearing.*

This should work (has worked for me in the pass).
If not please let me know.

Comment: Tried this as well and it worked, however using only a few lines of CSS I was able to achieve the same effect (see edits), although your method is probably more stable..

Comment: @Arkadelic Ok coolz... and yup, my delay method acts as a fail-safe for super slow loading times that may cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: absolute;` works partially, and renders this result:

[image]

All I had to do was add `left: 0; right: 0; and bottom: 50%;` to re-center the text. Also, resizing the window would cause scrollbars to appear, which was less than desirable, so I added `overflow:hidden;` to the body tag. Now this works exactly as intended:

[image]